# MFC: why it cannot pick up the right function based on argument type?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

In the program, I try to bring up a dialog when a menu item is clicked.

```
void CMyDoc::OnFileTest()
{
    m_dialog = new CMyDialog;
    m_dialog->Create(CMyDialog::IDD, GetDesktopWindow());
    m_dialog->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

When I hover on "Create" function (VS-2008 IDE), it shows two overloads.

```
Create(LPCTSTR..., CWnd *);
Create(UINT..., CWnd *);
```

But when I build it, why the compiler insists it should take the first one. How to fix it?

```
error C2664: 'BOOL CDialog::Create(LPCTSTR,CWnd *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from '' to 'LPCTSTR'
```

**Edit**

I try as suggested in the answer to cast IDD to UINT, but it doesn't work...

```
error C2664: 'BOOL CDialog::Create(LPCTSTR,CWnd *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'UINT' to 'LPCTSTR'
```

In fact, I copy the code from this project: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1651/Tutorial-Modeless-Dialogs-with-MFC, which can compile without cast.

One difference is that I use Create in Doc, while the above uses in Dialog ??

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the `CMyDialog` class - specifically, how the (presumably `static`) `IDD` member is declared and defined?

Comment: @AdrianMole These are standard variables declared by the system when creating dialogs in older Visual Studio versions.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Good point! I no longer use those auto-generated IDDs, and I had forgotten about their nature!

Comment: @AdrianMole My two projects started life in 2002 so have a lot of classes with these `IDD` definitions in. :)

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the header for your dialog and you will see, as an example:

```
// Dialog Data
enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG_ASSIGN_HISTORY };
```

Or you can hover the mouse over the `IDD` to see the definition:

[image: IDD]

Notice that the variable `IDD` is actually an `enum`? Specifically it is **not** of type `UINT`. As a result your compiler can't find the right override and ends up trying the `LPCTSTR` version, and fails.

As already answered, you need to cast your `IDD` variable,

```
m_dialog->Create(static_cast<UINT>(CMyDialog::IDD), GetDesktopWindow());
```

This way the compiler will not complain.

---

The Win32 SDK [`GetDesktopWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdesktopwindow) returns a `HWND` and not `CWnd *`. So you are back to the same scenario. You could casting to `CWnd *` or using `this` if that is acceptable.

From my research you should be able to do this to get a `CWnd *`:

```
CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FromHandlePermanent ( GetDesktopWindow());
```

I have been informed in the comments that there is a simpler solution:

```
m_dialog->Create(static_cast<UINT>(CMyDialog::IDD), CWnd::GetDesktopWindow());
```

See [`CWnd::GetDesktopWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2019#getdesktopwindow) for more info.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work, please check my new edit. Thank you.

Comment: In the article you referred to it doesn't specify the second parameter and is uses the default (`NULL`) in the function declaration.

Comment: There is a static function in CWnd class named GetDesktopWIndow() which returns a CWnd*.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Ah, you mean `CWnd::GetDesktopWIndow()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If `IDD` is an enumeration value you need to cast it to `UINT` in order to take advantage of that overload.

```
m_dialog->Create((UINT)CMyDialog::IDD, GetDesktopWindow());
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work, please check my new edit. Thank you.